# Django, uwsgi and nginx - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am quite new to python and am working on my first django project. I followed [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) tutorial. I managed to configure all the things but django app itself. It works if I run django server alone, however it does not work when started by uwsgi.

This is my uwsgi conf:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And error from uwsgi log:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

So I looked up for startup errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/www/api.partycon.net/virtualpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/api.partycon.net/virtualpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/var/www/api.partycon.net/virtualpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/api.partycon.net/virtualpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/api.partycon.net/virtualpy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named api.settings
```

My project's dirtree:

```
.
|-- api
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- media
|   |   `-- sample-media.jpg
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- static
|   `-- admin
|       ... ... ... ...
|-- uwsgi_conf.ini
`-- uwsgi_params
```

I hope I provided enough information, however I can tell u more - the problem is that I actually have no idea where to look.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably lacking a `chdir` line in your `uwsgi_conf.ini`. Or, probably, you have a `chdir` line, but it is wrong.

This is confirmed by your traceback:

```
File "./wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
```

Here you should see `./api/wsgi.py`, not `./wsgi.py`.

Clearly, the working directory of uWSGI is the `api/` directory, while it should be the parent directory.

In general, your uWSGI configuration file should look like this:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/path/to/your/project
module=mysite.wsgi:application
...
```

See also the [Django documentation on uWSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/).

Comment: Okay thanks @Andrea COrbellini. It helped me to move to the next stage: now I am getting this error in uwsgi log: `ImportError: No module named py \n
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)`

Comment: @ŽigaPatačkoKoderman: you have a trailing `py` somewhere. Perhaps, did you write `api.wsgi.py` instead of `api.wsgi`?

Comment: Thanks @Andrea Corbellini. True, i named wsgi file wsgi.py instead of api.wsgi. Thanke you very much :) and could you edit your post and add what you told me in this comments so the others can seen it easily?